# Laravel query using group by and where does not work

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This is a query that I have in raw sql.

```
DB::select('SELECT bldgs.name as building , floors.name as floor, areas.name as area, locations.area_id ,count(reqs.location_id) as occupied  FROM `reqs` '
           . 'JOIN locations ON locations.id = location_id '
           . 'JOIN areas ON areas.id = area_id '
           . 'JOIN floors ON floors.id = areas.floor_id'
           . ' JOIN bldgs ON bldgs.id = bldg_id '
           . 'WHERE `status`=2 and (DATE_FORMAT(start_date,"%Y-%m")<= "'.$dateFrom.'" AND DATE_FORMAT(end_date,"%Y-%m")>="'.$dateTo.'") group by locations.area_id, areas.name, floors.name, bldgs.name' );
```

And this is one of many attempts to make it work in Laravel elequent instead of raw.

```
Req::select('bldgs.name as building',DB::raw('count(location_id) as count_occupied'))   
    ->join('locations','locations.id','=','location_id')
    ->join('areas','areas.id','=','locations.area_id')
    ->join('floors','floors.id','=','areas.floor_id')
    ->join('bldgs as bl','bl.id','=','floors.bldg_id')
    ->where('reqs.status','=', '2') 
    ->where('start_date','<=', $date)
    ->where('end_date','>=', $date)
    ->groupBy('bldgs.name')
```

I need to understand why the second way gives mysql error and refuses to run the query above. Is is a mistake in my code or is this normally not possible in using eloguent to group by like this except in raw mysql string?

This is the error I get.

```
 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'bldgs.name' in 'field list' (SQL: select `bldgs`.`name` as `building`, count(location_id) as count_occupied from `reqs` inner join `locations` on `locations`.`id` = `location_id` inner join `areas` on `areas`.`id` = `locations`.`area_id` inner join `floors` on `floors`.`id` = `areas`.`floor_id` inner join `bldgs` as `bl` on `bl`.`id` = `floors`.`bldg_id` where `reqs`.`status` = 2 and `start_date` <= 2018-10 and `end_date` >= 2018-10 group by `bldgs`.`name`)
```

Comment: call `->toSql()` on your second query. It converts it into sql query then you can compare

Comment: If you eliminate the groupBy clause at the end, does the query work?

Comment: Include the SQL error in your problem, otherwise we're just guessing why the query won't run.

Comment: @Devon
Just included the error and it contains the sql generated.

Comment: @eResourcesInc Yes it runs without the group by, but I need to mention that it is extremely slow and consumes a ton of memory. I have to allocate more in php.ini. And it is not the query I want after all

Comment: @Devon I get the same error with and without the alias. Don't think this is the problem, because it can not identify the field in the select itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, you don't have a `bldgs.name` column.  You named the `bldgs` table `bl` when you joined it.

Rename your references from `bldgs.name` to `bl.name`.

Comment: Not working with or without the alias. I get the same error. The error seems to be near the select itself.

Comment: Then you must not have a bldgs.name column...   That's the only reason for this error.  Post the updated error if you updated the references.

Comment: The same field works for the raw query. I have posted it above in my question.

Comment: Ok, post the updated error.. otherwise I have nothing to go on.  It doesn't make any sense so you must have done something wrong.

Comment: Yes it is the same error in both ways.

   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'bldgs.name' in 'field list' (SQL: select `bldgs`.`name`, count(location_id) as count_occupied from `reqs` inner join `locations` on `locations`.`id` = `location_id` inner join `areas` on `areas`.`id` = `locations`.`area_id` inner join `floors` on `floors`.`id` = `areas`.`floor_id` inner join `bldgs` as `bl` on `bl`.`id` = `floors`.`bldg_id` where `reqs`.`status` = 2 and `start_date` <= 2018-10 and `end_date` >= 2018-10 group by `bldgs`.`name`)

Comment: Also this

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'bldgs.name' in 'field list' (SQL: select `bldgs`.`name` as `building`, count(location_id) as count_occupied from `reqs` inner join `locations` on `locations`.`id` = `location_id` inner join `areas` on `areas`.`id` = `locations`.`area_id` inner join `floors` on `floors`.`id` = `areas`.`floor_id` inner join `bldgs` as `bl` on `bl`.`id` = `floors`.`bldg_id` where `reqs`.`status` = 2 and `start_date` <= 2018-10 and `end_date` >= 2018-10 group by `building`)